# Map and match ranges in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, dictionary, match

What is the most effective to map ranges using Arrays in JavaScript?

I have this:

```
var def = [70,200,1000];
```

And an array of possible numbers, say:

```
var n = [23,45,74,120,240,800,1204,2000];
```

Now, **how can I extract the closest value from `n` that matches the values from `def`?**

In the example above, I would get `[74,240,800]`. I hope I make myself clear...

Comment: If `n` is sorted, you would need to do a binary search per entry in `def` and stop at the last visited, if not the actual target.  Removing the entry from `n` if no duplicate selections. This would be `o(#def . log #n)`, you could make it `o(#n)` if both were sorted by just passing through `n`, but that would be worse if `def` is small and `n` high.

Comment: If we can assume that `n` will be a sorted array, the logic would be something like: `iterate through n until a value greater than this is found. compare that value with the value from the previous index to determine which is closer to this`

Comment: Just a thought: if `def` is sorted, do we really need to loop through `n` every time?

Comment: Not if we assume both arrays are sorted. Otherwise, I believe you would need to iterate through n for each value in def.

Comment: Here's a solution for this in Python: `[min(n, key=lambda p: abs(d-p)) for d in def_]`. Sorry, I couldn't resist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8bY2M/

```
var def = [70,200,1000];
var n = [23,45,74,120,240,800,1204,2000];

var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < def.length; i++){
    var val = def[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < n.length; j++){
        var nVal = n[j];                
        if (nVal > val){
            var closest = n[j-1] == undefined ? nVal : 
                nVal - val > val - n[j-1] ? n[j-1] : nVal;

            result.push(closest);
            break;
        }    
    }
}

console.log(result); // outputs: [74, 240, 800]
```

Note that this will go with the larger value in the event of two matches. (i.e. if you are trying to match 70, and n contains 66 and 74, this will match it with 74)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a try. Iterate over `def` and `n` just once:

```
var nIndex = 0,
    nlen = n.length,
    prev,
    next;

for(var i = 0, ilen = def.length; i < ilen && nIndex < nlen; i++) {
    var current = def[i];

    while (n[nIndex] < current && nIndex < nlen - 1) nIndex++;

    next = n[nIndex];
    prev = nIndex == 0 ? next : n[nIndex - 1];

    result[i] = current - prev < next - current ? prev : next;
}
// values in def are larger than the greatest value in n
while (result.length < def.length) result.push(n[nlen-1]);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u8x3E/3)

Comment: Nice, but is it possible to get it with readable vars so I can follow? It looks a bit like assembler now... Also, the fiddle link is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions are pretty simple, but if you're looking for efficiency, your best bet is to pre-sort the initial list (if it's not sorted already) and then perform a binary search. Here's my solution:

```
var def = [70,200,1000];
var n = [23,45,74,120,240,800,1204,2000];

var findClosest = function(n, def) {
    var i, result = [];

    n = n.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; }); //numeric sort


    var closestN = (function(val) {
        return (function search(r) {
            var mid = r.low + (0 | ((r.high - r.low) / 2));

            if(n[mid] === val) { 
                return n[mid];
            }

            if((r.high - r.low) === 1) {
                return n[r[(Math.abs(n[r.low] - val) > Math.abs(n[r.high] - val)) ? "high" : "low"]];
            }

            r[(val < n[mid]) ? "high" : "low"] = mid;

            return search(r);
        }({low : 0, high: (n.length - 1)})); 
    });

    for (i=0; i<def.length; i++) {
        result.push(closestN(def[i]));    
    }

    return result;
};

//The result can be obtained with findClosest(n, def)
```

Mind you, it's not very readable (if you're not familiar with binary search algorithms) and if you're looking for a simple solution where performance isn't important, a linear search would result in more maintainable code. But this solution runs in O(n log(n)) time, instead of O(n^2) time like a linear search would.

You can see it in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/naYu6/

Note that in the case of a "tie" (where two values in the list are equidistant from the value in question, the lower of the two will be picked).